# How to properly load one ajax request after another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a messaging system for a website that I am making. Basically, it consists of clicking one button and two Ajax Requests afterwards. I am not even sure I am going about this the right way. On click of the button the first Ajax starts to call. The first ajax request loads a file that loads the style of the messages and retrieves them from a database. The problem I am having is that the first request sometimes takes to long to finish and the other request does not get complete. Another problem I am having is that if I put an "animation delay" type thing on it then it will look like the page it running slow. You can run an example at "http://www.linkmesocial.com/linkme.php?activeTab=mes" you must type or copy and past the whole length for it to work otherwise you will redirect to the login page. Any advice would be AWESOME! If there is some easier way to set up a messaging system please feel free to give me some advice or direct me to a tutorial. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

### I would also like the know if this is a good practice. Please :)

---

My Original file. On click of class "mes_tab" a form is submitted. also the function mes_main() is called.

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$messages = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipient='$username'");
echo "<div id=\"mes_main-bar_top\" class=\"center\">Messages</div>";
echo "<div id=\"mes_main\">";
echo "<table id=\"mes_main-allView\" class=\"left\">";
echo "<td class=\"mes_tab-change\" >^</td>";
$from=array("","","", "", "", "", "", "");

for ($msgCount = 0; $msgCount < 8; $msgCount++){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($messages);
    $from[$msgCount] = $row['sender'];
    for ($prev = 0; $prev < $msgCount; $prev++)
    {
        if ($from[$msgCount] == $from[$prev] )
        {
                $cont = true;
                break;

        }
    }
    if ($cont)
    {
    $cont = false;
    continue;
    }
    if ($row['message'] == ""){
        break;  
    }

    echo "<tr><td class=\"mes_tab\" onclick=\"mes_main('" . $row['sender'] .  "')\">";
    echo "<h3 class=\"center\">" . $row['sender'] .  "</h3>";
    echo "<form id=\"" . $row['sender'] .  "\" >";
    echo "<input name=\"sender\" value=\"" . $row['sender'] . "\" hidden/>";
    echo "<input name=\"id\" value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\" hidden/>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</td></tr>";

}


if ($msgCount == 8)
{
echo "<td id=\"mes_tab-change_bottom\" class=\"mes_tab-change\">V</td>";
}
echo "</table>  <!-- end mes_main-allView -->";

echo "<div id=\"mes_main-mesView\" class=\"right\">";

echo "</div>    <!-- end mes_main-mesView -->";

echo "</div>    <!-- end mes_main -->";
```

---

mes_main() function from above. The two ajax functions inside are what I am referring to in the post above.

```
function mes_main(x)
{
var sender = x;
$( sender ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

});


ajax_req_mes("scripts/home/php/mes_load.php?" + sender , "mes_main-mesView");
ajax_req_mes("scripts/home/php/mes_content.php?" + sender ,"mes_content");



}
```

---

mes_load.php

the $sender var is created by passing the sender username through the URL. That is why I do  php explode on the url.

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$sender = explode('?', $url);
$recieved = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipient='$username' AND sender='$sender[1]'");
$sent = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipient='$sender[1]' AND sender='$username'");

echo "<div id=\"mes_content\"></div>";
echo "<div id=\"mes_field\" class=\"right\"></div>";
```

---

mes_content.php

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$sender = explode('?', $url);
$recieved = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipient='$username' AND sender='$sender[1]'");
$sent = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipient='$sender[1]' AND sender='$username'");


echo "<table id=\"mesView-table\">";

$REC = array();
$SENT = array();

$ID = array();



for ($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++)
{


$rec = mysqli_fetch_array($recieved);
$sent = mysqli_fetch_array($sent);


    if ($rec['id'] > 0)
    {
    $REC[$i] = $rec['id'];
    }


    if ($sent['id'] > 0)
    {
    $SENT[$i] = $sent['id'];
    }



}

$ID = array_merge($SENT, $REC);
sort($ID);

    for ($x = 0; $x < count($ID); $x++) 
    {
    $key = $ID[$x]; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = '$key'");
    $res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if (in_array($key, $REC))
        {

            echo "<tr><td class='mes_recieved'>";
            echo $res['message'];           
            echo "</tr></td>";
        }
        elseif (in_array($key, $SENT))
        {
            echo "<tr><td class='mes_sent'>";
            echo $res['message'];       
            echo "</tr></td>";              
        }


    }

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us? It will help us to help you. You could always call the 2nd request in the done() portion of the original request, because done() acts as a deferred.

Comment: I added code. All of it from beginning to end. I connection requests of course.

Comment: I actually dont think that I need the form that is prevented since I changed the way I am doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set async to false in your ajax requests!That's how the second one will wait for completing the first one and then start.
Also you can catch the on success and on error for the purposes you have.

Comment: Mode following changes to code:

ajax_req_mes("scripts/home/php/mes_load.php?" + sender , "mes_main-mesView", false);
ajax_req_mes("scripts/home/php/mes_content.php?" + sender ,"mes_content", false);


It seems to work better but the results are still inaccurate in the fact that it does not load every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "success" and "error" callbacks.

Also you could use the ["done" callback](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

But, IMO, for that kind of problem I think a better alternative would be using [Websockets](https://www.websocket.org/quantum.html)

EDIT:
Here is some example of how you could do it:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : {msg:"your message"}
        url : "http://fu.com/myfile.php",
        success: function(response){
            //Do something with your response
        }
}).done(secondCall());

function secondCall(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : {data:"data"}
        url : "http://fu.com/myfile.php",
        success: function(response){
            //Do something with your response
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT2:
For visibility, here is a tutorial using websockets: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

Comment: You need to provide some example code for the OP so that a solution can be tried. This is more of a "comment" than an "answer".

Comment: Is this a better service for messaging? I want to do as secure as possible.

Comment: It's are more elegant and better solution. Can't say it will be more secure though. Here is a link that explain websockets using by doing a  [chat example](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket)

Comment: It seems better. Another question is... Is this only if both users are online? (like chat room based messaging) or can it send to offline users as well?

Comment: The example is only for online users, but it wouldn't be much different... The only difference would be that you need to store the message instead of sending it through socket. So you would have to store the messages in a DB with an state of "sent"/"seen" and then push the messages to the user when he login (in case there is any message pending).